# Change display URL in struts 2 to hide request parameters

Tags: java, html, url, struts2, query-string

I know very well that using GET method and passing request parameters in URL is a **bad practice** and **security vulnerability** . But we are in a situation where project development is almost completed and we can not afford to change all the GET to POST and re-test the whole thing all over again.

Is there a way to change the displayed URL ?

Or URL encoding will do the job ?  Please suggest what could be the best approach in this situation.

Comment: Where did you get that idea? The right method for the right purposes.

Comment: I was looking for a quick fix to buy time , will definitely fixed it with the legitimate approach in next project iteration ;)

Comment: MohammedAnwar, @AleksandrM is telling you that GET doesn't implies a security vulnerability (though querystrings are pretty ugly), and according to the literature, you should use GET for idempotent method (read), and POST for non-idempotent method (insert, update, delete). However the willing to remove querystring is absolutely legit, hence my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way exists, it is the HTML5 History API.

It needs JavaScript and [HTML5 compliant browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history), or a [javascript fallback for old IE (eg History.js)](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#history).

Take a look at [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29_method) and [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29_method) methods: the first alter the current history entry, the second adds a new one (creating noise in back button usage, so I suggest the first).

To remove the QueryString (the `?param1=value1&param2=value2` part) just run this script on page load:

```js
<script>

    $(function(){
        history.replaceState("","",location.href.substring(0,location.href.indexOf("?")));
    });

</script>
```

While this client-side solution definitely improves clearness and eye candy, I doubt it improves security at all; [Post-Redirect-Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) would be better, but if you can't, then use this technique.

I generally use PRG in conjunction with this to achieve pretty URLs, and it works perfectly.

Note that this is a simulated PRG, an F5 after the page is loaded might have unpredictable behaviors ***according to how you've programmed your application***.