# Action class is called twice

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2, action

I have been dealing with this kind of situations here and there. In my Struts 2 application, I'm using an AJAX call to send a String array to an Action class. What I'm trying to do is something like this: `page_1.jsp` -> `Action A` -> `Action B` -> `Action C`. However, what is actually happening is `page_1.jsp` -> `Action A` -> `Action B` -> `Action C` -> `Action C`, i.e. the last Action class is being called twice.

**page_1.jsp:**

```jsp
<button class="ink-button double-vertical-space all-25 dynamicButton" 
           id="finish" disabled> Finish </button>
```

**[...]**

```jsp
$('#finish').click(function(event)
{
    var fids = $('input:checkbox').filter(':checked').map(function ()
    {
        return this.id;
    }).get();

    $.ajax
    ({
        method: "POST",
        url: "A.action",
        data: { fids : fids },
        traditional: true,
        success:
            function()
            {
                // I know that the problem is here. 
                // Currently I have it like this, so it's understandable 
                // why action C is getting called 2 times, 
                // I just don't know how to fix it.
                window.location = "C.action"; 
            }
    });
});
```

**struts.xml:**

```jsp
<action name="A" class="action.A" method="execute">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction"> B </result>
</action>

<action name="B" class="action.B" method="execute">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction"> C </result>
</action>

<action name="C" class="action.C" method="execute">
    <result name="success"> /page_2.jsp </result>
</action>
```

Comment: Remove the line and it's done.

Comment: What's `$('#finish')`? A submit?

Comment: @RomanC: I've already tried that. If I remove `window.location = "C.action"`, the Actions are called correctly (and Action `C` will be called only once), but `page_2.jsp` will not be rendered.

@DaveNewton: `#finish` is a button, but not a submit one (I don't have a form in the JSP page):

`<button class="ink-button double-vertical-space all-25 dynamicButton" 
           id="finish" disabled> Finish </button>`

Comment: @jaff It should be already rendered on the first call.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing strange things. If you want to perform some operations and go to a new page, then why are you using AJAX ? I guess not to let the user work meanwhile:

> user runs the AJAX call, then starts working on something else, and in the middle of the unsaved work... PUFFF! The page changes because the AJAX response is come back.

That would be weird, uber-annoying and a clear violation of [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

BTW, if you still want to do it AJAX way for some reason I can't imagine right now, then you can do it in two ways:

1. If you want to draw **page_2.jsp**, as it seems, then return a `dispatcher` result (or `stream`, or `json`, or whatever is NOT a `redirect` nor `redirectAction`) from your **Action.B**, then your `window.location = "C.action";` will call **Action.C** the right (non-AJAX) way.
2. If instead you want (but it seems NOT your case) just the URL to reflect the new action, use [`history.pushState()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18916695/1654265) or [`history.replaceState()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647640/1654265) instead of `window.location()`. They won't trigger any request, and the URL will be the new one.

Comment: I understand your doubt. I'm just using AJAX because I need to send a String array (`fids`) to the Action class (`A`) and this is the only way I know to achieve that. I imagine that more suitable solutions exist, I just don't know them, so if you think there is a better way of doing this, feel free to point it out.

Comment: @jaff: How about just creating a form and submit?

Comment: @jaff then look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15343980/1654265 I guess it's the only thing you're missing

Comment: In fact (and as it can be seen in the code above), `fids` contains the IDs of the checkboxes that are checked, when `#finish` is pressed. I've already removed the AJAX call, added a form and turned `#finish` into a submit button, but although I have used the `status` parameter before, I just can't seem to reproduce what I was doing initially (with the AJAX call). Since comments can't handle code properly, I can edit the question and put there my efforts so far, if you want - but perhaps this is going off-topic? Anyway, I guess this is another example of an XY problem :\

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="fids[0]" value="foo" />,<input type="hidden" name="fids[1]" value="bar" /> ,etc